# aws glacier restore -- PowerShell/cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

`aws s3api restore-object --bucket $_.Bucket --key $_.PreFix --restore-request --restore-request Days=7,GlacierJobParameters={"Tier"="Standard"}`

I get this error msg:

> The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment
> operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as
> a variable or a property.

This was the recommended format from AWS -- any help appreciated

Comment: this was the actual code sample aws s3api restore-object --bucket $_.Bucket --key $_.PreFix --restore-request Days=7,GlacierJobParameters= {"Tier"="Standard"}

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the $*.Bucket and $*.PreFix?

I am not familar with powershell. I guess $_ should come from somewhere and they are missed.

Can you simply replace those variables to plain text?

For example:

```
aws s3api restore-object --bucket your_bucket_name --key object_key_to_restore --restore-request --restore-request Days=7,GlacierJobParameters={"Tier"="Standard"}
```

https://aws.amazon.com/tw/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restore-s3-object-glacier-storage-class/